# ViewDidLoad state does not seem to refresh once I logout and login

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So my view controller namely "HomeViewController" basically displays a **label** and two buttons, **connect** and **logout**.

Once the view is loaded, my label basically has a background colour of **white** and a text that says **"Press the connect button"**. When I press the **connect** button, the label changes the text to **"Please wait, waiting to connect you with someone"** and the background colour changes to **yellow**. Then I perform some firebase queries and connect the user with someone. Once connected, I change the label colour to **green** and text to **"You have now been connected"**.

Everything works just fine except that I have two issues:

1. When the view loads, I am calling a function `fetchUserDet()` that fetches user details and stores it in a declared object `User`. I use this `User` object to access details of the currently logged in user, details like name, age etc. When I logout and login as a different user however, the `User` object just fails to get the details of the newly logged in user and returns nil.

   Temporary fix: I am calling the `fetchUserDet()` function yet again in a `viewWillAppear()` function but I guess this is bad practice but gets the job done. Now my `User` object is assigned to the newly logged in user
2. Say I press the connect button, the label changes colour and text as expected but when I log this user out and login as a different user, the label and text remains in the state as it was for the previous user. Ex: Logged in as **user 1** and press **connect** button, label changes colour to **yellow** and text to **"Please wait, waiting to connect you with someone"**. When I logout and login as **user 2**, it remains in the same state as **yellow** and **"Please wait, waiting to connect you with someone"**

I am guessing both these bugs are interconnected and I am definitely doing something wrong here. I am using **Firestore**. Here is the code for your understanding.

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import ProgressHUD

class HomeController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: Initialize
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        fetchUserDet()
    }
    
    var currentUser: User!
    var connected: Bool? {
        didSet{
            print("Step 7 - Connection has been established at didset")
            self.connectionLabel.backgroundColor = .green
            self.connectionLabel.text = "You are now connected. Start texting"
        }
    }
    
    let connectionLabel: UILabel = {
       let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Press the connect button for a new connection"
        label.textColor = .white
        label.backgroundColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()
    
    let signoutButton: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Logout", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSignout), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    let connectButton: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Connect", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleConnect), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    // MARK: View Did Load
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        fetchUserDet()
    }
    
    // MARK: Signout
    
    @objc func handleSignout(){
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
            navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch let error {
            print("Failed to signout", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Connection Handle
    
    @objc func handleConnect(){
        self.connectionLabel.text = "Please wait, finding you a match..."
        self.connectionLabel.textColor = .black
        self.connectionLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        self.connectButton.isEnabled = false
        self.connectButton.backgroundColor = .black
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(handleTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        
        guard let cUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        let gender = currentUser.gender!
        
        //Connection Operation : This function does the connection work
        connections(gender: gender, cUid: cUid)
    }
    
    // MARK: Connection Algorithm
    
       connections(gender: String. cUid: String) {
         //Perform the database connections and algorithm
         //If connection is established, I set the isConnected variable to true
         self.connected = true
    }

    @objc func handleTime() {
        self.connectButton.isEnabled = true
        self.connectButton.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    // MARK: Authenticate / Views
    
    fileprivate func fetchUserDet(){
        if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
                navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            configureViewComponents()
            configureUserDetails()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Configure Components
    
    func configureViewComponents(){
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [connectionLabel, signoutButton, 
          connectButton])
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: 
           view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 20, left: 0, 
           bottom: 20, right: 0))
    }
    
    // MARK: Configure User Details
    
    func configureUserDetails(){
        guard let cUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(cUid).getDocument { (snapshot, error) 
           in
            if let error = error {
                print("There was an error fetching the current user details ", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            let dictionary = snapshot?.data()
            self.currentUser = User(dictionary: (dictionary)!)
            print(self.currentUser!)
            print("Step 1 Gender")
            print(self.currentUser.gender!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `HomeViewController` getting pushed/presented from somewhere else? Have you tried calling your function in `viewWillAppear()` instead?

Comment: What happens when you log out? Does it stay in `HomeViewController` or pops/dismissed to somewhere else?

Comment: This is a very low quality question, a huge story telling rather than a question. The question isn't clear

Comment: @MumtazHussain Thanks for your response. HomeViewController has a shared key window with the LoginController. It checks if current user has signed in and if not, it presents the LoginController. You can see this part of the code in fetchUserDet() function in the code I posted

Comment: @MumtazHussain To answer your second comment, I am simply presenting the LoginController. You can check this in the function handleSignOut() in the code above. Sorry to keep reverting you to the code.

Comment: @Archid instead of presenting, you should simply dismiss the HomeViewController when you log out.

Comment: @MumtazHussain Thanks! Will try that and notify you

Comment: @AnkurLahiry Thanks for commenting. I understand, I guess I posted the whole story out of panic cuz I have to get this thing to work. Wanted to give every detail possible

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you must learn to use push/pop and present/dismiss and when to use what in order to keep yourself out of navigation problems, for example your handleSignOut method should be popping/dismissing the current HomeViewController to get to previous view controller of Login.

```
@objc func handleSignout(){
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi..I tried dismissing the controller during sign out but that didn't work as well. This is what is happening:

Comment: Everytime I run the build for the first time and sign in the user, my firestore seems to save nil values for the User object. So when I force unwrap it, it crashes. But when I logout and run the build again for the second time, my user object works. Now if I log in and log out, user object is set for other users who are logging in as well. But again, another bug is the state of the app remains the same as for the previous logged in. I'm guessing there is something missing. And I am guessing both these bugs are connected. Always the first time I press build fails but second time works.

Comment: Ok I solved the part where the User object was not getting set. Turned out, that during login, I was only calling the configureComponents() function instead of calling  fetchUserdet() func. Now the only bug is, when I sign out and sign in as a different user, the view did load displays the UILabel in the state of it's previous user